# move single route 53 A record under acm wildcard to ACM in separate aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53, aws-acm

I have an app deployed in aws **account B**, until now I had an acm certificate in **account A** for `mydomain.com` and `*.mydomain.com` and a hosted zone in account A with an A record for `myapp.mydomain.com` pointing to the alb in **account B**, so far this worked fine. Now the app needs to be moved to a new domain "mydomain.xyz" while at the same time maintaining support for the previous route. I proceeded to create a `mydomain.xyz` acm in **account B** and got the DNS delegated and the acm was validated, now my app is live under "myapp.mydomain.xyz" but it lost the SSL support under the previous `myapp.mydomain.com` even though nothing was changed in **account A**.

I'm thinking I need to update the acm in account B to also list the previous domain and update the DNS delegation, but wanted to make sure Im going in the right direction.

Also there's other records set up in route 53 in account A using the wildcard acm, is there any risk by adding the domain to the acm domain list in account B for any of the other domains listed in account A?

Comment: Where your app is hosted?